# Trusting a specific client with golang mutual TLS auth

Tags: ssl, go

I've had a successful TLS mutual authentication client/server setup in Go for a while, but now looking to make some small tweaks.

Specifically, I'm wondering if there is a way to require only a specific client certificate for mutual auth.

I'm currently using something like this:

```
    // Load cert and build pool
    caCert, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(caPath)        
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    // Require client authentication
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        ClientCAs: caCertPool,
    }
```

Which works fine, however if the PEM file I'm reading in is actually a certificate chain (A issued by B, and B is a root CA), this will actually end up trusting any certificate issued by B, which I don't want.

Is there any way I can tweak this code to ONLY trust the specific A certificate?

It seems that if I only include A in the loaded PEM file, the [server handshake code](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/handshake_server.go#L424) tells the client "send me all your certs signed by A", which of course is not what I want, as cert A is not signed by A.

Ideally I'd want to say "you require specifically certificate A" to connect successfully. Is there such a mechanism?

Comment: doesn't using a middle CA for this solve the problem? a non-root CA for your service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no mechanism to do this for you, but starting with [go 1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#crypto_tls) you can specify your own callback using the `VerifyPeerCertificate` field in the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) object (this works both on the server and client side).

This takes a method with the following signature:

```
func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error
```

Per the docs:

> It receives the raw ASN.1 certificates provided by the peer and also
>   any verified chains that normal processing found.

The certificate validation has already run, so you only need to apply your specific logic: examine the leaf certificates (first in each chain) in `verifiedChains` and check that the certificate is in the list of allowed certificates (just `A` in your case). If it is not: return an error and the handshake will fail.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. I've got it implemented and it works perfectly. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Be careful though: I edited my answer a few times and originally mentioned looking at `rawCerts`. That was wrong, you definitely need to look at `verifiedChains`.

Comment: Correct, thanks for the edits. I'm iterating through verifiedChains to compare certificates against a specific cert I'm looking for.